# MVC: Having static method in models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, static

**Concise**: How I can avoid using static methods in a model?

**Loquacious**: Suppose I have a user class. Having userID I can get user name by `(new user($userID))->getUserName()`. Fine, what if I want to lookup a user? `(new user())->lookup($uname, $pass)`. Still fine, but the latter case could be done via a simple static method `user::lookup($uname, $pass)`!
Some thoughts:

- It's OK! Use `(new object())->method()` whenever you want. So should I create a hollow object to call a function?
- Move this function out of your model. If it needs a DB lookup, where is better than Model context?
- Define it as a static method. So isn't it lame to have a mixture of public and static methods in a class?

**Side note**: I've searched this question, no avail!

Answer (score 2):

*Move this function out of your model. If it needs a DB lookup, where is better than Model context?*

Yes, indeed, this is the best way to solve the problem.

Currently your `User` class violates single responsibility principle which basically, says "one task - one class".

Right now your `User` describes user entity/state and handles persistence (in your case - retrieval from database). See, two things.

I suggest you create another class that is going to handle persistence tasks, like add/update/delete user. The simplest solution is to create a primitive repostitory, like this:

```
<?php
class UserRepository
{
    public function addUser(User $user);

    public function updateUser(User $user);

    public function deleteUser(User $user);

    public function getUserById($id);
}
```

Then retrieval of user can be done in the following manner:

```
// get an instance of this repository class
$userRepository  = new UserRepository;

// ask it to find and return user from the database by ID
$user = $userRepository->getUserById($_GET['id']);
```

Easy to read, easy to handle, right?

This `UserRepository` class is actually a *primitive* implementation of Repository Pattern. `UserRepository` emulates an in-memory collection of all of your users, hiding implementation inside. It *hides* actual persistence mechanism from you as user: imagine, your coleague would write this class and you're just using its methods, like `UserRepository::getById(1)` - you don't even know/care if it grabs data from files/db/API. That's neat. )

This particular implementation is described very clearly in Kristopher Wilson's book "The Clean Architecture in PHP", which I highly recommed for you to read: it will take you two-three evenings, and push you to the next level.

You can extend the list of methods, of course, add lookups, etc.

```
class UserRepository
{
    public function getByCompany(Company $company);

    public function getByEmail($email);

    public function countTotal();
}
```

In fact, every time you need to grab/add/update user in the database, you should do it via this repository.

I would like to emphasize that this is a simple implementation of the pattern, particularly, if you compare it to what [Martin Fowler describes as Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). However, in most cases it's totally fine.

Comment: Thanks @Georgy, Suppose I switch things to the structure you mentioned. WHat about methods like lookup, where I have to place this method?

Comment: These methods should also be implemented in your `UserRepository`. I'll add details to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

- It's OK! Use (new object())->method() whenever you want. So should I create a hollow object to call a function?

  depends on how much creating an instance will cost
- Move this function out of your model

  Factory Pattern comes in mind here.

  notes here:

  What happens when `$userID` in the first call do not exists?

  Isnt your `lookup()` method not creating 2 instances at one call, first for lookup, second the found one that is returned?

A FactoryPattern for example can have `findByID()` or `findByName()` and return an UserObject. And all that should not depend on this syntax at all: `(new object())->method()`, that is nice, but not always best practise.

Comment: I see, but what should I do?

Comment: The `UserRepository` implementaion above is one way, and he has some very good points. Seperate as much as possible. The `User` Class should in the end nothing more than bunch of setter an getter of properties.

Comment: I still want to know should I put this method as static or not? Should I move it out of user class?

Comment: Why not let the User class do `_construct($id or [$n,$p]);` and do the lookup internal on the args that are give? Whatever, i had also questions for you to thing about, your major problem is the structure of your application (that not can only use MVC) and that cant answered here. My short answer woulde be: Do it like you want, all is possible, but not everthing is good.

Comment: Are you suggesting to let my user class accept userID or even user name and password?

Comment: `suggesting` not really, but since you always repeat the same question: in or out, static or not? i just 'suggest' that you can do it many/any ways. I thing you should read a documention of a framework like symphonie a and look how they are done it, read little more of using MVC or HMVC and other types and then you may fins out what is the best way for you